# Is there a portable scanner connect to an android phone?

Tags: document-scanner

I dont know whether my question is right to ask here. please advise me if I need to ask this kind of question at other areas.

I am investigating to find a right portable scanner to connect with an Android mobile phone (such as HTC Desire). After scanning a paper from a portable scanner, the mobile phone will receive the file as a pdf or jpg. That's it!

Would this be possible to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to look for Bluetooth scanners. Android supports bluetooth and there is SDK API for it so you could create your own app to receive and process data from scanner.

One such device I could find: http://www.planon.com/products/docupen/xseries

Answer (score 2):

Android has USB host capabilities as of 3.2. Accusoft USB Scanner is a well made app that lets you take advantage of this and connect many USB scanner models directly to your phone or tablet.

[Accusoft USB Scanner](http://www.accusoft.com/usbscanner.htm)

[Accusoft USB Scanner on Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.accusoft.usbscannerfree&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmFjY3Vzb2Z0LnVzYnNjYW5uZXJmcmVlIl0.)

Comment: The second link is dead. An update is required here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to connect a USB scanner to an Android device - most if not all phones don't have a USB host in any form. I suppose someone could hack an adapter into the MicroSD port, but it'd be a lot of work. You'll have to use a laptop or computer.

Comment: Hi Jam. Thanks but most of the android Phones that have a USB port and I thought that a portable scanner would use a USB port to plug in with a PC so it would be doable with a mobile device as well. I hope there would be a solution...

Comment: Android phones have a USB _slave_ port, which means they can't talk to other slave devices. (well, maybe they can, but it would involve a _lot_ of hacking)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of scanners like that.  Query "bluetooth document scanner for android"  About 15 will show up.  5 at least from amazon